# Checkbox not showing up on android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been trying to add a checkbox to my android app's layout but it is not showing up. The text field beside the checkbox is displayed but the checkbox itself remains invisible. How can this be fixed ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Write your name"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Topping"
         android:textSize="50sp"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="500sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="new checkbox"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:buttonTint="#000000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried to run the code? sometimes you need to clean the project to make it work

Comment: Try set check box width to "wrap content" and see the result.

Comment: @nassertahani nothing happens on setting the width to "wrap_content"

Comment: @Souravgupta Try to use `dp` instead of `sp` in `layout_width` and `layout_height`. and also reduce the `textSize` to `20sp` or lower.

Comment: Why you are using `scaleX` and `scaleY` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this checkbox xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new checkbox"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:buttonTint="#000000"/>
```